# Why are some images rendering on IE6 and some are not?

Tags: php, html, css, image, internet-explorer-6

the images are showing up in safari and firefox but not IE6. I have four images, two of them are showing up in IE6 and two are not. If it helps, they are being toggled with an if statement. suggestions?

Here is an example of the code, there are four of these chunks:

```
                 <div class="NavIcons">
                    <a href="http://www.blah.org/MyQuestions.php?id=<?php echo $prof->id; ?>"
                        <img src="http://www.blah.org/styles/images/<?php if($ProfileIcon == "questions") { echo "Red"; }else{ echo "Grey"; } ?>QuestionNew.jpg" border="0"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you could point us to an example.  Also, are they all the same file type (e.g. jpg, gif, png)?

Comment: Which ones do show and which don't?

Comment: also, can you view the images in IE by just typing their full URL into the browser? If you can't, the problem is with the image, rather than the code.

Answer (score 3):

Check the images directly in the web browser affected.

```
<img src="http://example.com/styles/images/<?php
   if($ProfileIcon == "questions") {
     echo "Red"; 
   } else {
     echo "Grey";
   } ?>QuestionNew.jpg" border="0" />
```

Would work out to:

```
http://example.com/styles/images/RedQuestionNew.jpg
http://example.com/styles/images/GreyQuestionNew.jpg
```

If you can get the JPGs to load correctly then that should solve it. Some possible causes of a JPG that won't load: saved as a different format than JPG but saved with .jpg extension, saved in CMYK colorspace rather than RGB, upload of file was incomplete, permissions problems with the file. Though the last two are unlikely because they're visible in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the images are not CMYK, they will need to be RGB.